# pandas parse csv with left and right quote chars

Tags: python, csv, parsing, pandas

I am trying to read a file in pandas which is structured as follows

```
<first>$$><$$<second>$$><$$<first>$$>
<foo>$$><$$<bar>$$><$$<baz>$$>
```

using `pd.read_csv('myflie.csv', encoding='utf8', sep='$$><$$', decimal=',')`
will fail to produce a meaningful result. All data is read into a single colum, and quotes are not extracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need escape `$` by `\`, because it is read as regex (end of string):

> (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex)

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO


temp=u"""<first>$$><$$<second>$$><$$<first>$$>
<foo>$$><$$<bar>$$><$$<baz>$$>"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), 
                 encoding='utf8', 
                 sep='\$\$><\$\$', 
                 decimal=',', 
                 header=None, 
                 engine='python')

print (df)
         0         1           2
0  <first>  <second>  <first>$$>
1    <foo>     <bar>    <baz>$$>
```

And then for remove `$$>` from last column is possible use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) (added `&` for end of string):

```
df.iloc[:, -1] = df.iloc[:, -1].str.replace('\$\$>$', '')
print (df)
         0         1        2
0  <first>  <second>  <first>
1    <foo>     <bar>    <baz>
```

And for remove quoting:

```
df = df.replace(['^<', '>$'], ['', ''], regex=True)
print (df)
       0       1      2
0  first  second  first
1    foo     bar    baz
```

Both replace together:

```
df = df.replace(['^<', '>$', '>\$\$'], ['', '', ''], regex=True)
print (df)
       0       1      2
0  first  second  first
1    foo     bar    baz
```

Comment: How can I additionally remove the quotes <> ? The regular pandas quotes paramter takes only a single char e.g. " but I need a left and right quote char.

Comment: I.e. is there abetter way than looping over all columns and executing both calls `df[0] = df[0].str.replace('<', '')
df[0] = df[0].str.replace('>', '')
df`

Comment: Wow great answer.

Comment: How could I add the header for the replacement as well? Curently I would use col = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.replace('<', ''))
col = pd.DataFrame(col, columns=['col'])
col = col.col.map(lambda x: x.replace('>', '')).values
df.columns = col
df.head() which seems to relly pythonic.

Comment: I think the simplier is `df.columns = df.columns.to_series().replace(['^<', '>$', '>\$\$'], ['', '', ''], regex=True)`

Comment: Great. This is even quicker.