# pandas parse csv with newlines

Tags: python, csv, pandas, awk, newline

A while ago I used quotes on both sides of my data and read it into pandas [pandas parse csv with left and right quote chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627091/pandas-parse-csv-with-left-and-right-quote-chars) now, I also need to support newlines and some weird characters.

Minimum sample below, the first string (`temp`) will  work just fine, but the second one won't parse properly.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""<first>$$><$$<second>$$><$$<first>
<foo>$$><$$<bar>$$><$$<baz>"""

temp=u"""<first>$$><$$<second>$$><$$<third>
<foo>$$><$$<bar>$$><$$<baz>
<foo>$$><$$<Green; kkkk 101; aaaa, bbb; [foo<1>>aaa<123>>xxx<1>>zzz<1.17989207 | 18187681 | asdf |>>
;sdf{ 

}
;ADD{

]>$$><$$<baz>"""

big_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), 
                 encoding='utf8', 
                 sep='\$\$><\$\$', 
                 decimal=',', 
                 engine='python') # we cant use pandas optimized C parser due to our special delimiters.

big_df.iloc[:, -1] = big_df.iloc[:, -1].str.replace('\$\$>$', '')
big_df.iloc[:, -1] = big_df.iloc[:, -1].str.replace('\$\$>$', '')
big_df = big_df.replace(['^<', '>$'], ['', ''], regex=True)

big_df.columns = big_df.columns.to_series().replace(['^<', '>$', '>\$\$'], ['', '', ''], regex=True)
big_df
```

## edit

As outlined in the comment - when putting all onto a single line it works just fine. 
**How could I automate this maybe via sed/Awk?**
`awk '{printf("%s ",$0)} END{print ""}' sample.csv` will remove *all* new lines and concatenate everything into a single line. I would rather only want to remove the problematic newlines.

`awk -F, 'NF < 4 {getline nextline; $0 = $0 nextline} 1' sample.csv` will already remove the normal newlines. But still there are the additional blank lines.

Comment: When I manually remove the newlines, parsing works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your "real" newlines are marked with `$$>\n`. Read your file in to string, replace `$$>\n` with something temporary, remove any remaining newlines, reinsert the "real" newlines, then pass to read_csv().

```
temp = temp.replace('$$>\n', '%%NEWLINE%%').replace('\n','').replace('%%NEWLINE%%', '\n')
big_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), ...)
```

Comment: Sorry, I needed to update the sample. They are only marked with `>\n` and `df |>>\n` is causing issues here as well. But your idea is good i.e. extending the pattern to `>\n<` seems to work. Is there a possibility to speed this up using sed/awk /pyhton multiprocessing?

Comment: You could use a multiprocessing process pool to chunk the input file but if you want to do the processing on `big_df` in a single process beware that serializing dataframes between processes is not fast.